# Access is denied for WriteProcessMemory function

Tags: c++, winapi

When WriteProcessMemory function is called it causes a System Error Code - 5.

I have tried `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` and `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` both but it doesn't work anyway.

Here is code:

```
int intToWrite = 123;

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, /*ProcessId*/);

if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x..., &intToWrite, 4, 0) != 0)
{  
 std::cout << "Everything is fine. \n";
} 
else
{
  std::cout << "The problem " << GetLastError() << " is in WPM function. \n";
}
```

Output in the console is:

```
The problem 5 is in WPM function
```

So, where is my mistake exactly about access?

Comment: Documentation calls for PROCESS_VM_WRITE and PROCESS_VM_OPERATION. You fail to meet that. Checking the return value of OpenProcess is strongly advised.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did as you said but and now it shows that problem in WPM function.

Comment: @ArtemLeshchukov - begin from fix code here to `OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`, check it return value and actual error code after api fail

Comment: @RbMm Ooooh, it works well! Amazing! But what does the character 'I' mean between P_V_W and P_V_O?

Comment: [bitwise OR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: @RbMm Ok, thanks, but... why is it so necessary to have bitwise OR in such a case like with me?

Comment: @Artem Because that's how bitflags work. Try some websearch on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the process with write access is not enough, you must also ensure that the memory you are writing is writable ([VirtualProtectEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex)).

Comment: No. WPM takes care of that for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course not. "Remarks
WriteProcessMemory copies the data from the specified buffer in the current process to the address range of the specified process. Any process that has a handle with PROCESS_VM_WRITE and PROCESS_VM_OPERATION access to the process to be written to can call the function. Typically but not always, the process with address space that is being written to is being debugged.

The entire area to be written to must be accessible, and if it is not accessible, the function fails."

Comment: You've read that wrong. By accessible it just means that the addresses are valid that process. Protection is taken care of by WPM. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181206-00/?p=100415

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nevertheless it is better to unprotect the pages yourself to avoid relying on implementation details.